# wp_list_categories with category description

Tags: categories

It seems to me that `category_description` should be an option in `wp_list_categories`. Is there way to pull the description when listing all categories?

Comment: This is just an HTML list of links - that's why it doesn't get descriptions. You probably want `get_categories()` which will give you more freedom on what to display and how to display it. Also, there _is_ an option `use_desc_for_title` if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I adjusted the title to have less opinion-based answers (i.e. removed the "why" part)

Answer (score 1):

### Extend the `Walker_Category` class

We can extend the `Walker_Category` class to append the *category description* to each item.

Here's a demo example with an *anonymous* class (PHP 7+):

```php
$args = [
  'walker' => new class extends Walker_Category 
    {
      public function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )
      {
        // Let's use the output from the parent's start_el method
        $output .= parent::start_el( $output, $category, $depth, $args, $id );

        // Append the category description:
        $desc = $category->description;
        $output .= ( $desc ) ? sprintf( '<span>%s</span>', esc_html( $desc ) ) : '';
      }
    }
];

wp_list_categories( $args );
```

For older PHP versions, we can just define the class as usual with a custom name.

Here's a single item output example:

**Item before:**

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-269">
    <a href="http://example.tld/category/green/" 
       title="Description for the Green category">Green</a>
</li>
```

**Item after:**

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-269">
    <a href="http://example.tld/category/blue/" 
       title="Description for Green category">Green</a>
    <span>Description for the Green category</span>
</li>
```